# How do we proof this in integers modulo n.

Tags: proof-verification

Let's say we have four integers, $\phi$, $\theta$, $\omega$ and $\zeta$. 
Where we define $\omega$ and $\zeta$ to be co-prime.

What I have to show (or prove?) is the following statement:

The equivalence classes of R match with the elements of the integers modulo $\zeta\omega$. Where with 'integers modulo cd' I mean: $\mathbb{Z}_{\zeta\omega}=\{[0], [1], ..., [\zeta\omega-1]\}$ (The set of the equivalence classes)

This means:

The equivalence class of $\phi$ under $R$ is the same as the equivalence class of $\phi$ in $\Bbb Z_{\zeta\omega}$.

I am absolutely clueless as to how I should approach this proof.

---

Comment: Hint: $\,c,d\mid n\iff cd\mid n\,$ since $c,d$ are coprime (e.g. by Euclid's Lemma or FTA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a specific example.  Take a couple of primes for $c,d$.  I suggest small ones like $2$ and $3$ so there are not many cases.  The equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z_6$ are then $[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]$.  Now see what integers are in the same equivalence class with $0$ under $R$.  It turns out they are the same ones as in the class for $\Bbb Z_6$.  What you are trying to show is 
$$aRb \iff (b-a) \equiv 0 \bmod 6 \iff (b-a) \in [0_6]$$
or the same with $6$ replaced by $cd$.  The first comes from your definition of $R$, the second from the definition of $[0_{cd}]$

Your statement "This means" should say "the equivalence class of $a$ under $R$ is the same as the equivalence class of $a$ in $\Bbb Z_{cd}$

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed to get started. I had to translate the proof from a different language into english so this really helped.